# JS plugin/library to show and create reservations

Tags: javascript, reservation

I'm making a website for a doctor. His clients must be able to reserve appointments online. Appointment in DB is described by fields - from (timestamp), to (timestamp), description (varchar 200).

Clients must be able to make an appointment from Monday to Friday on each whole hour (07:00, 08:00, 09:00 etc.), from 07:00 to 21:00. They must see which hours are already 'reserved' and which are 'available'.

The doctor must be able to see these reservations in some way and do a basic CRUD (accept, deny, update, add some notes …).

I googled around and didn't find anything great. [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) seems to be the best so far, but it still involves a lot of customization.

Answer (score 2):

I recently made a detailed analysis about what is available of [open source resource scheduling software](https://edgeryders.eu/t/6629). From that list, my recommendations for your case would be as follows, starting with the most suitable one:

- **[Easy!Appointments](http://easyappointments.org/).** Free and open source software, written in PHP, and coming with a WordPress plugin. Geared towards the special use case of booking appointments at a doctor etc.. Nice simple step-by-step reservation process. [The source code](https://github.com/alextselegidis/easyappointments) has >1200 commits and is still maintained.
- **[Booked Scheduler](https://www.bookedscheduler.com/).** Uses FullCalendar and needs no custom development, only installation and configuration. This is by far the most sophisticated version, but can also be a bit complex to understand and manage for a simple use case.
- **[EDD Bookings](https://eddbookings.com/features/).** A WordPress plugin for booking appointments. Similar to Easy!Appointments, but with payment integration. Still in active development. Though the software is sold on the website, it is [licenced GPL3](https://github.com/RebelCode/eddbk/blob/develop/LICENSE) and the code is available publicly: [backend](https://github.com/RebelCode/eddbk), [JavaScript frontend](https://github.com/RebelCode/bookings-js), [other stuff](https://github.com/RebelCode).